# I need to create an excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to compare a value with standard default value and find out a answer.

For Example:- If 200gb takes 2 hrs how much will it take for 250gb? how to put this in formula?

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic. To start a formula, the first symbol of the cell must be `=`. If you divide 120/200 (min/gb), you can simply multiply the amount of `GB * 0.6`.

Even better would be to have a cell with the ratio, so you can adjust it visibly and not only in the cell. So for example, cell `A1`should have value `0.6`.

If you then have a column of amount of GB's you wish to convert, let's say from `B1 -> B10`. In cell `C1` simply type: `=B1 * $A$1` and click on the bottom right corner to drag the formula up to cell `C2`.

In case you don't know: adding a dollar sign `$` before a cell row/column prevents it being incremented when being dragged to other cells.